# What figure of speech or idiom is involved here?

Tags: slang, figurative-language

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2WxaeIJcqY

So I found this line: "You're a sewer troll that Stephen King wrote between his lines" in a rap music and I was trying to understand how it somehow referred to cocaine. Is a figure of speech involved here, or is this some kind of slang or idiom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a reference to the figure of speech [**to read between the lines**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-read-between-the-lines), meaning to understand something that is not said openly, and to *lines of cocaine*: [Stephen King was a heavy user of cocaine](https://www.rollingstone.com/culture/culture-features/stephen-king-the-rolling-stone-interview-191529/) at the time he wrote IT, the novel which features Pennywise the clown, so the sentence is implying that Stephen King created the character of Pennywise, in his *lines* of writing, in between doing *lines* of cocaine.

[image]

Comment: Is it some kind of figure of speech or something else? I've never seen something like this. To me, it's nonsensical.

Comment: @Sayaman - it is _extremely_ unwise to expect normal, or even usual English in rap lyrics.

Comment: Ok, is there a category for non-formal rhetorical or figurative techniques?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's any specific term for this, formal or otherwise (although almost every rhetorical technique seems to have a name) - it's just a kind of wordplay, blending the meanings of two words or phrases.

Comment: This could be considered an example of "allusion": the rapper is alluding to King's cocaine use.

Comment: @Sayaman It's lyrical or poetic, or some might call it "colorful".  "Wordplay" is also appropriate as stangdon pointed out.  The fact that this phrasing is layered and complex while being concise is what makes it artisitic and valuable as a lyric.

Comment: It's weird, because "writing" is not used in a metaphorical way, it's used in a wrong way, but I don't know any figure of speech that involves using a word incorrectly.

Comment: @Sayaman Why do you think "writing" is used in a wrong way here?

Comment: He's putting powder and not writing.

Comment: @Sayaman  I don't understand your comment.  Stephen King wrote the character; he did this in between lines (of cocaine).  *Lines*, in the original rap, is a punning reference to both lines of writing and lines of cocaine.

Comment: So writing is a metaphor for putting powder on his book to sniff it?

Comment: No, it doesn't imply he was putting powder on the book.  I am starting to think there is something different about the wordplay that you don't understand.  You understand that "between his lines" can mean between in *time*, not just physically, yes?

Comment: ah between in time... he wrote the character between his lines of cocaine?